# Use powershell to install office LTSC from GPO

Tags: powershell, office365, gpo

As the title suggests I am trying to get Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021 installed via gpo.

I have followed microsofts instructions on using their deployment tool and their configuration tool to setup everything properly.

When I run a batch script in the directory calling the setup and pointing it to the config everything processes properly but I am trying to run it through powershell for a cleaner install.

Through my searches I came across someone who used powershell to check for previously installed versions, removed them, and installed the 2021 version. I have modified this code and set it up as a startup script in our GPO and I cannot get it to run the script.

I am fairly new to powershell so I have been trying to teach myself throughout this process.

```
#Check for Office 2021 installation
    $officeInstall = Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration' 'ProductReleaseIds'
    
    if($officeInstall -eq "ProPlus2021Volume"){
     Exit
    }
    
    if($officeInstall -eq "ProPlus2019Volume"){
     #Uninstall 2019
     $now = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
     Write-Output $now "Office 2019 found, uninstalling" >> c:\Office2021.log
    
    \\data\Shared\OfficeDeploymentTool\setup.exe /configure \\data\Shared\OfficeDeploymentTool\ConfigRemoveOffice2019.xml
    }
    
    #install office 2021
    $now = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    Write-Output $now "Installing Office 2021" >> c:\Office2021.log
    \\data\Shared\OfficeDeploymentTool\setup.exe /configure \\data\Shared\OfficeDeploymentTool\ConfigTesting.xml
```

Comment: Does your script create the `c:\Office2021.log` file? Computer policies launch scripts as the System user for that machine, and often will not have access to network shares like your `\\data\shared` folder.

Comment: It doesn't create that log file at all.
Our shared drive is mapped that it should have access everywhere but even then signing in any user should hit the startup right? Is there a better way youd suggest doing that?

Comment: Can you add how you created the policy to launch the powershell script? When you run gpupdate on a client, does it process successfully?